# How create Dropdown list only using ViewBag in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

Here I have a model class..

```
public class MyDrop
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I use this code....

```
public ActionResult Index(){

    var GenreLst = new List<MyDrop>();

    MyDrop a = new MyDrop();
    a.id = 1;
    a.value = "hello";

    MyDrop b = new MyDrop();
    b.id = 2;
    b.value = "hello2";

    GenreLst.Add(a);
    GenreLst.Add(b);
    ViewBag.ShowDropDown = new SelectList(GenreLst); 


}
```

Then in my view I add this code...

```
@Html.DropDownList("ShowDropDown", "All")
```

After run the project.It show a dropdown list.
But not showing correct values.

In the page source it likes this....

```
<select id="ShowDropDown " name="ShowDropDown "><option value="">All</option>
<option>DropDown.Models.MyDrop</option>
<option>DropDown.Models.MyDrop</option>
</select>
```

How do I solve this???

I was Expected like this.....

```
<select id="ShowDropDown " name="ShowDropDown "><option value="0">All</option>
<option value="1">hello</option>
<option value="2">hello2</option>
</select>
```

Please Help......

Comment: You need to specify the `Value` and `Text` properties of `SelectList` - `ViewBag.ShowDropDown = new SelectList(GenreLst, "id", "value");` Note that the first option will be (and needs  be) `<option value="">All</option>` (not `value="0"`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index(){

    var GenreLst = new List<MyDrop>();

    MyDrop a = new MyDrop();
    a.id = 1;
    a.value = "hello";

    MyDrop b = new MyDrop();
    b.id = 2;
    b.value = "hello2";

    GenreLst.Add(a);
    GenreLst.Add(b);
    ViewBag.ShowDropDown = new SelectList(GenreLst, "id", "value"); 


}
```

In your View:

```
@{
SelectList list = ViewBag.ShowDropDown;
}

@Html.DropDownList("DROPDOWNID", list, "All")
```